# How to search with LINQ entites having string[] array properties and find these containing any of string from string[] array?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, iqueryable, ef-core-2.2

With EF Core 2.2 I am having entities with `string[]` array properties, where in **ApplicationDbContext** they are retreived with:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<FruitBasket>()
            .Property(e => e.FruitTypes)
            .HasConversion(
                v => string.Join(',', v),
                v => v.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

For example an entity mat contain in FruitType column an strning array: `{"Apple", "Banana", "Orange"}` saved in the database as: `Apple,Banana,Orange`

I am trying to find in my DB all objects containing any of string from my input string, lets say any of:

```
string[] BasketSearchedFruitTypes = new string[] { "Apple", "Grapefruit", "Pineaple" }
```

My IQueryable:

```
IQueryable<BasketModel> baskets = GetBasketsQueryable(); //BasketModel contains FruitType string[] prop
```

To search for entities I have right now LINQ that says:

```
if (search.BasketSearchedFruitTypes != null && search.BasketSearchedFruitTypes.Length != 0)
baskets = baskets
   .Where(data => search.BasketSearchedFruitTypes
   .Any(x => data.FruitType
   .Contains(x)));
```

Unfortunatelly it returns me nothing and I ran out of ideas.

**EDIT 1:**
after using expression:

```
baskets = baskets
   .Where(data => search.BasketSearchedFruitTypes
   .Any(x => data.FruitType
   .Contains(x)));
```

when I try take it to the List<>, I am getting `ArgumentNullException`. Also I am not able to use `foreach`, `.Count()` on it. Same I have with:

```
var result = baskets.Where(data => search.BasketSearchedFruitTypes.Intersect(data.FruitType).Any();
```

**EDIT 2:**
I just noted, that foreach loop goes through returned IQueryable, but at some point breaks giving `ArgumentNullException`. Even `try catch` inside of the loop does not help...

**EDIT 3:**
Actually when I place `foreach` of returned IQueryable into `try catch`, it is kind of temporary solution and it works fine. But still I do not understand why it crashes on enumerating (looping, not code inside of the loop).

Comment: You can try this way `var result = baskets.Where(data => search.BasketSearchedFruitTypes.Any(x => x.Contains(data.FruitType)));`

Comment: @Phong `data.DetailedType` gives me an exception where can not convert `string[]` to `char`

Comment: you can use [`Intersect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=netframework-4.8) to achieve it 
`var result = baskets.Where(data => search.BasketSearchedFruitTypes.Intersect(data.FruitType).Any();`

Comment: @Phong it still gives me no results

Comment: If you remove `Where` clause, What is the result that you get?

Comment: I think that I am even not able to do that

Comment: You should debug to find out the root cause. Firstly, make sure that `baskets` without `Where` clause return items (You can give us some sample record to help us to be able to reproduce your problem)

Comment: Can you extract data without any clause but just a tolist?

Comment: @MarcoSalerno yes, complete list from DB, or other LINQ expressions work fine for me, just double checked now... Right now I wonder if I can split expression somehow into 2 and debug it, but Im not sure that it is possible

Comment: Please also note, that after using my expression I am getting `ArgumentNullException`. Also I am not able to use `foreach`, `.Count()` on it. Same with @Phong LINQ

Comment: I think that I found a problem. In my DB I had entities having `NULL` values in `FruitType` column. So now I have to figure out how to get rid of them in query. Thank you guys for your time!

Comment: P.S. I just add: `.Where(data => data.FruitType != null).Where(rest of oryginal expression)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I make a list similar at your DB protocol Than this codes work for me.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class BuilderClass
    {
        List<BasketModel> baskets;

        public BuilderClass()
        {
            baskets = new List<BasketModel>() 
            { new BasketModel { FruitType = new string[] { "Apple", "Grapefruit", "Pineaple", "Bing Cherry", "Cantaloupe" } },
              new BasketModel { FruitType = new string[] { "Grapefruit", "Cantaloupe", "Pineaple", "Boysenberries", "Apple" } },
              new BasketModel { FruitType = new string[] { "Clementine", "Bing Cherry", "Boysenberries", "Cantaloupe", "Entawak" } },
              new BasketModel { FruitType = new string[] { "Entawak", "Grapefruit", "Apple", "Pineaple", "Cantaloupe" } },
              new BasketModel { FruitType = new string[] { "Apple", "Pineaple", "Bing Cherry", "Entawak", "Grapefruit" } }
            };
        }

        string[] BasketSearchedFruitTypes = new string[]
        { "Apple", "Grapefruit", "Pineaple" };

        public void check()
        {
            var qbaskets = baskets.AsQueryable();
            if (BasketSearchedFruitTypes != null && BasketSearchedFruitTypes.Length != 0)
            {
                var result = qbaskets.Where(data => BasketSearchedFruitTypes.Any(x => data.FruitType.Contains(x))).ToList();
                // result have list with count of 4
            }
        }
    }

    class BasketModel
    {
        public string[] FruitType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution worked fine. After investigation I realized, that my nullable values were causing a problem. But I mark your reply as a proper solution for my question.